# Spring-boot JPA not generation table automatically

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have a `Spring-boot` application. I need `Spring-boot` to generate a table for me automatically but it is not working. I came across a lot of information but none technique has worked.

I am getting an Exception saying:

> The relation `fire_csv` does not exist

Code:

> Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private FireCsvService fireCsvService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {      
        fireCsvService.save(new FireCsv());

    }
```

> FireCsv.java

```
@Entity
public class FireCsv {  

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String accountNumber;       
    private String accountType; 
    private String bankClientIdNumber;  
    private String accountOpeningDate;  
    private String accountClosingDate;  

   //getters and setters
```

> DataBaseConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
public class DataBaseConfiguration implements EnvironmentAware {

    private RelaxedPropertyResolver jpaPropertyResolver;

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private PersistenceUnitManager persistenceUnitManager;

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.jpaPropertyResolver = new RelaxedPropertyResolver(environment, "spring.jpa.");
    }   

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("jdbcTemplate")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        if (persistenceUnitManager != null) {
            entityManagerFactoryBean
                    .setPersistenceUnitManager(persistenceUnitManager);
        }
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.fire.api.form");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap().putAll(jpaPropertyResolver.getSubProperties("properties."));
        Map<String, Object> properties = entityManagerFactoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap();
        properties.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", jpaPropertyResolver.getProperty("hibernate.naming-strategy", SpringNamingStrategy.class.getName()));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", jpaPropertyResolver.getProperty("hibernate.ddl-auto", "create-drop"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect");
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .url("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/fire-api")
                .driverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver")
                .username("postgres")
                .password("pass")
                .build();
    }   
}
```

> FireCsvServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class FireCsvServiceImpl implements FireCsvService {

    private final FireCsvRepository fireCsvRepository;

    @Inject
    public FireCsvServiceImpl(final FireCsvRepository fireCsvRepository){
        this.fireCsvRepository = fireCsvRepository;
    }
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public FireCsv save(final FireCsv fireCsv) {
        return fireCsvRepository.save(fireCsv);
    }
```

> Stacktrace

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:809) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:790) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:777) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.opessoftware.fire.api.Application.main(Application.java:25) [main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:242) ~[spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:225) ~[spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:521) ~[spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761) ~[spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.tPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730) ~[spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:485) ~[spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291) ~[spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.opessoftware.fire.api.Application.run(Application.java:30) [main/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:806) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Fi:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3124) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3581) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:465) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:351) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1258) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517) ~[spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "fire_csv" does not exist
  Position: 13
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2103) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1836) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:334) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Add @Table annotation to the entity bean. If it doesn't work, share what you have in fireCsvService.save() and exception stack trace.

Comment: @uday I edited the post with the new information you asked

Comment: Couple of missing things here: 1. Annotate the entity with @Table. 2. Make sure that the table name follows the SQL standards i.e. all lower case. In case you have no control over this, use quotes to delimit annotations.

Comment: @uday I did it, I put `@Table` annotation and still does not work, I also tried `@Table(name = 'firecsv')` and now it says that the relation `firecsv` does not exist.

Comment: It should be @Table(name = "fire_csv"). Name attribute should be the exact table.

Comment: Also did not work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I solved the problem.

The problem was that some `columns` were `too big` for the database to create, so the table creation was failing then the app was trying to write and and throwing and exception saying that the table does not exist.